# Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, glassfish

I want to configure glassfish with my db. 
I create jdbc ressource like this:

- jndi name: jdbc/MysqlDataSource
- pool name : MysqlConnPoll

And i create my connection pool like this:

- Pool Name: MysqlConnPoll
- Ressource type: java.sql.driver
- Driver classname: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

in Additional Properties

- databaseName: name_db
- user: root
- password: ****
- url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name_db
- Port: 3306
- ServerName: localhost

I add **mysql-connecter-java** and **com.mysql.jdbc** in "glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext"

And when i ping my connection with the site glassfish, i have this message

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for MySqlConnPoll. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Please check the server.log for more details.
```

Why i have this message ? i forgot something ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your driver name is wrong.

For ConnectorJ version 8 try:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
```

For older ones:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
```

This is how to configure the **Datasource Classname** field for MySQL 8:

[image: Datasource Classname setting]

Answer (score 1):

I've just learnt JDBC last week, not sure I can help.

I have got something like this too after creating a new domain in glassfish4.0 and try to create a connection pool with that new domain. After a few tries and errors, I got it to work.

I added the connector .jar in "glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib" rather than inside the "glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext" like you mention. Maybe you can try that and see.

not sure if this help: while connecting to database, I also use the same .jar (meaning pointing to the same file) when specifying the driver.